Updates about supervision with roboflow
That's the code i'm using to set YOLO.
generator = get_video_frames_generator(SOURCE_VIDEO_PATH)
box_annotator = BoxAnnotator(color=ColorPalette(), thickness=4, 
text_thickness=4, text_scale=2)

iterator = iter(generator)
frame = next(iterator)
results = model(frame)
detections = Detections(
xyxy=results\[0\].boxes.xyxy.cpu().numpy(),
confidence=results\[0\].boxes.conf.cpu().numpy(),
class_id=results\[0\].boxes.cls.cpu().numpy().astype(int)
)

labels = \[
f"{CLASS_NAMES_DICT\[class_id\]} {confidence:0.2f}"
for \_, confidence, class_id, tracker_id
in detections
\]

frame = box_annotator.annotate(frame=frame, detections=detections, labels=labels)

%matplotlib inline
show_frame_in_notebook(frame, (16, 16))

Then, it gives me the next error:

init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colors'

How can i solve that?

I have imported supervision's classes as the following:
from supervision import ColorPalette, Point, VideoInfo, get_video_frames_generator, VideoSink, plot_image, Detections, BoxAnnotator, LineZone, LineZoneAnnotator
Is that ok?

This should probably be an [edit], not a comment.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
